# why isn't $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} = 1$ for $u(x,y) = x$ on $y = x^2$?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

\begin{cases}
        u(x,y)=x, \quad \text{for} \quad y = x^2 \\ 
        u(x,y) = 0, \quad \text{everwhere else}.
    \end{cases}

Suppose we parameterize with $t$ as follows:

$x(t) = 3t$,

$y(t) = 9t^2$.

So, we have $y(t) = (x(t))^2$.

Suppose we are interested in the point at $t = 0$.

I am confused by the expression
$$
\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} = 0.
$$

I understand that the main message (chain rule does not apply here) does not change. But I do not see mathematically why $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} = 0$ and $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} \neq 1$.

From the limit definition, I can see that $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} = 0$ at $t=0$, or at $(x,y)=(0,0)$,

$u_x(0,0) = \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{u(\Delta x, 0) - u(0, 0)}{\Delta x} =  \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{0 - 0}{\Delta x}  = 0$

but I want to know what's prohibiting from me just getting $$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} = \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{x}} = 1$$

**(Optional context)**

We want to compute $\frac{du}{dt}$ at $t=0$.

Since $x$ and $y$ satisfies $y(t) =(x(t))^2$ at $t = 0$, we have:

$$\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{d(x(t))}{dt} = 3$$

My confusion comes from when the author tries to teach that the chain rule cannot be applied here when computing $\frac{du}{dt}$.

The author writes the chain rule:

$$
\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{t}} + \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{t}}
$$

and shows that the result is

$$
\frac{du}{dt} = 0\cdot3 + 0\cdot 0 = 0,
$$
which is different from the above result (equal to 3) and the author goes on to state that the chain rule is invalid due to $u_x$ and $u_y$ not continuous at $(x, y) = (0, 0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \begin{cases}\begin{align} 0, \quad &y \neq x^2 \\ \text{undefined}, \quad &y = x^2 \end{align}\end{cases}.$$

Roughly speaking in a very informal way, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ goes to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ at any point that satisfies $y = x^2$. It is actually undefined at these points. So applying the chain rule would mean multiplying a number by an undefined value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but isn't $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} = 0$ for $x=0$ and $y=0$ by the limit definition? And $(x,y)=(0,0)$ satisfies $y = x^2$?

Comment: Yes, it is defined exactly at 0 as 0. However, as Carlos states, it’s undefined everywhere else on the curve $y=x^2$ (which runs through (0,0)), so it’s undefined in a neighborhood of the origin, so it isn’t continuous at the origin as the chain rule requires.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that the expression I wrote is only valid for $y \neq 0$, since $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$ for $(x,y)=(0,0)$. But still $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \neq 1$.

Think about what happens when you fix $y$ and sweep the $x$ axis - Even at $y=0$, the curve $f(x) = u(x,0) = 0$ for all $x$, thus $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0 \neq 1$.

Comment: @Eric, okay I think I understand that part and so I cannot use the chain rule. My question is when computing $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}$, why can I not just use the fact that $u = x(t)$ and thus  $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} = 1$.

Comment: @CarlosPrete Is it not legal to just take the derivative on $u(x,y) = x$ with respect to $x$ since it's not equal to $x$ everywhere around that point?

Comment: u only equals x on that curve. Elsewhere it is 0. If you fix y, u is effectively 0 everywhere except 1 point, so the partial derivative is 0 everywhere except for at that point (on the curve) where it isn’t defined.

Comment: @Eric okay, thanks, is it okay to say that the normal rule of differentiation (i.e., derivative of $2x$ w.r.t. $x$ equals $2$) does not work here because $u(x,y)$ is defined piecewise?

Comment: Ehh, derivatives might only work on the boundaries of piecewise functions if they line up. In this case, the boundary is the entire curve $y=x^2$, they only are continuous at the origin, and the partial derivatives aren’t defined elsewhere. 

Note that it is possible to define piecewise curves where it does work. For example, $f(x)$ defined as 0 for negative x and $x^2$ otherwise does in fact have a derivative at 0 despite its piecewise nature.

Comment: @Eric, okay thanks it's helping me get a better understanding.
So, even when the boundary lines up (in this case, at the origin), I cannot just perform the normal differentiation rule I mentioned above, but instead must compute the derivative with the limit definition since functions are technically different across the boundary, right?

Comment: It doesn’t work since the partial derivative aren’t defined everywhere near 0.

Answer (score 0):

Where is unclear is the definition

Write :

$$ u : (x,y) \to u(x,y)$$ is null on $$\mathbb{R} - \Delta $$

where $$\Delta=\{(x,y), y=x²\}$$

So

On $\Delta$ define

$$ g : x \to u(x,x²) $$

On $\Delta$ **you cannot apply**

$$ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)=\dfrac{dg}{dx}(x)=\partial_1u(x,y)+2x\partial_1u(x,y)$$

**because partial derivative are the traduction of all directions derivations**

Comment: thank you for the answer but it's difficult for me to understand the last part, could you provide an easier explanation, please?

Comment: What do you mean the "traduction of all directions derivations"?